# using X-PATH over other options

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Why should I use functions to find elements, like `find_elements_by_id` or `find_elements_by_class`, when I can easily do that with `find_elements_by_xpath`?

(I know that in Selenium 4.0 we don't use these functions anymore, instead we use `find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class"))` but still, can someone explain it to me, I would very appreciate any advice)

Comment: Try `find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Class name" and "ID" of the elements don't often change to a different name. If you search for elements with xpath, it can change for example with every new section added to the page.

Example before a new section gets added:

```
find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class"))
find_element(By.ID, "id"))
find_element(By.XPATH, "div/div"))
```

Example after a new section gets added:

```
find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class"))
find_element(By.ID, "id"))
find_element(By.XPATH, "div/div/div/a"))
```

Result:
If you were finding elements with xpath, you'll have to change all the xpaths now. The class name and Id stayed the same.

A way more effective way is if you write your own xpath.

Example:

```
//a[contains(@class,'something')]
```

How? -> https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html